# react native animation : screen shaking when scrolling slowing

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I am using `Animated.View` to change the header height.

It works well in ios but in android, when I scroll slowly the entire view is shaking.

1) First I set the state

```
 this.state = {
      scrollY:new Animated.Value(0)
   }
```

2) Inside the `render()` I render the height of the view I want to animate.

```
const HeaderHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 100],
      outputRange: [100, 0],
      extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })
```

3) I set my Header like this:

```
  <Animated.View style={{width:'100%', height:HeaderHeight, backgroundColor:'transparent', justifyContent:'flex-end'}}>
 ...
  </Animated.View>
```

4) Inside the scrollview:

```
<ScrollView
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
          onScroll={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY } } }])}
          >
```

As you could see from the gif file when I `slowly scroll the view` the screen is shaking. This is happening in android. On ios it works fine.

Any idea how to fix this?

Any comments or advice would be really helpful :)

[image]

Answer (score 20):

**Your inputRange [0,100] and outputRange[100,0] have a ratio of 1.**

This means that for each pixel you move in the ScrollView, your HeaderHeight will be reduced by one, which sounds great but the value you get from the scrollview event is not an integer, is a double and based on those tiny digits it will try to "aspect ratio" your outputRange and this is quite sensitive in Android and therefore the shaking.

**Increase your inputRange to [0, 200] so it has a ratio of 2 related to the outputRange. This will remove the shaking.**

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been struggling with it for a few days

Comment: Thank you so much. Saved my day. I never suspected this.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a little tricky but try to avoid set translate prop to FlatList`s style, or component that wrap Flatlist, jumps will disappear. For adding empty space before first item you can set contentContainer={{paddingTop:}}. It was in my case, hope this help someone.

Answer (score -3):

Make your `scrollview` animated.

```js
<Animated.ScrollView 
            style={{flex: 1}}
            onScroll={Animated.event([
              { nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.scrollY } } }
            ])}
          >

...
...
</Animated.ScrollView>
```